# Sort multidimensional array by index

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Assuming we have the following array:

```
$edibles = [

    ['Apple', 250],
    ['Pear', 300],
    ['Cherry', 270],
    ['Tomato', 300],
    ['Carrot', 240],
    ['Potato', 170]

];
```

What would be the best way to sort those items by **item[1]**?

There are no array keys present which is why the google results didn't help me very much.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sure, if you're talking about 250, 300, 270, etc. the array key is `1` as you've stated.

Comment: Post the expected result..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php):

```
usort( $edibles, function ( $a, $b ) {
  return $a[1] - $b[1];
} );
```

Comment: Thank you. That article was exactly, what I was looking for. Will accept the answer when available.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the values from index `1`, sort that and then sort the original on that using `array_multisort()`:

```
array_multisort(array_column($edibles, 1), SORT_ASC, $edibles);
```